# How to get Symfony2 connected with SQL Azure?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, azure-sql-database

Is there somebody who was already successful with this topic?
I already tried to write a custom Doctrine platform, but it isn't as easy as I thought.

*By the way this is the first question tagged with [sql-azure] [symfony-2.0]* :/

Answer (score 1):

check https://github.com/beberlei/AzureDistributionBundle
this should already work, at least for simple symfony2 applications.

Comment: This bundle eases the deployment of an application on Azure, not connect it to Azure SQL.