# Windows Azure : MySQL database working with Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, azure

I host a Symfony2 project on the Windows Azure services.
I'm trying to extract my database from the virtual machine.

I see there is two ways of create database in Azure :

- Azure SQL Databases
- ClearDB MySQL

Is there any way to make the doctrine/MySQL thing easily works on the Azure SQL ? Or is it reserved to Microsoft SQL stuffs ?

For the ClearDB option, if anyone of you configured one with Symfony2 project, which plan did you subscribed to ? The free plan up with 4 connections doesn't let an heavy Symfony2 project run, what about the Venus plan up to 15 connections ?

Otherwise, is there any database service you recommend to run a Symfony2 project ?

Thanks !

edit : what the "up to X connections" actually means for my app ? means that if more than X visitors, the service will not respond ?

Comment: Azure SQL Database is a version of SQL Server, not a generic database hosting solution. That said, you *can* get Doctrine to talk to Azure SQL Database. It just won't be MySQL. :)

Comment: Ok ! Is that painful to achieve ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number means concurrent connections. Typically you will need one connection per request, and for a small-scale website 15 concurrent database connections is enough.

As for using Azure SQL Database for your app -- it's already been answered before: [How to get Symfony2 connected with SQL Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140912/how-to-get-symfony2-connected-with-sql-azure)

Comment: Thanks. When doctrine perform multiple queries during a user request, does it count as one connection ?

Comment: Yes, the usual pattern for a web application is to open a connection, perform a number of queries using that connection and then close it.

Comment: That's weird. It means with a ClearDB instance if I pay 50$/month, i can't deal with more than 30 concurrent users...

Comment: Back in 2005 I was able to serve up to 100 concurrent *users* with a connection pool that rarely went above 12 concurrent *connections* -- remember that your users' requests will rarely arrive at the same instant, and the connection attempt will block for at least the duration of the timeout. That means that when concurrent user 31 comes along, their request will be served the moment concurrent user 1's page load is finished.